# Merge two rows based on a column in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I have a pandas dataFrame like this:

```
   version    ids
0  001        {'id': '121'}
1  001        {'id': '122'}
2  002        {'id': '123'}
```

How do I convert every value of **ids** to a **list** and also combine them based on the **same version**?
Here is what I would like:

```
   version    ids
0  001        [{'id': '121'}, {'id': '122'}]
1  002        [{'id': '123'}]
```

I've tried group by:

```
df.groupby(['version'])['ids'].apply(','.join).reset_index()
```

but it didn't turn out to a "list", What's the right way to do this?
Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with

```
df.groupby(['version'])['ids'].agg(list).reset_index()
```